# Синонимизировать метки [widgets] и [виджет]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать эти метки:

- [widgets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widgets) (142 вопрос)
- [виджет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82) (65 вопросов)

Comment: Тогда уж и в ед. числе можно добавить `widget`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 148 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 142 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 137 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'widgets': [widgets] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 202
tag remapping of [виджет] and [widgets] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
6 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym widgets -> виджет was approved!
```

И добавил [widget](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widget) как синоним.